# How to use a React Hook `useWindowSize` to initialize window size inside a MobX Store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have `win()` function inside `FrameItStore` which returns `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight`. But it doesn't always update when window size changes.

## FrameItStore.ts

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'

export class FrameItStore implements IFrameItStore {
  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      win: observable,
    })
  }

  win(): Window {
    return {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    }
  }
}

export const config = new FrameItStore()
```

So I want to use Window Size Hook → https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/window-size to get updated dimensions.

Problem is I don't know how to initialize the `win()` function with the hook value as hooks can only be called in React Component?

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are storing the window dimensions outside of your React components, you could update them outside of the React components as well if you would prefer.

**Example**

```js
import { makeObservable, observable, action } from 'mobx';

export class FrameItStore implements IFrameItStore {
  win = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  };

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      win: observable,
      updateWin: action.bound
    });
    
    // Update this.win every time the window resizes
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWin);
  }

  updateWin() {
    this.win.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.win.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  
  // If your FrameItStore won't live for the entire duration of the application,
  // you can call this method to remove the event listener.
  destroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWin);
  }
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't make use of Hooks. This just writes the whole window size code in the class `FrameItStore`. Can't I set the hooks tuple value & set it in MobX Store while initializing & update it somehow?

Comment: I dropped the hooks package & used your method but would love to know the answer to my question :)

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Yes, it doesn't make use of hooks, but I think for this particular use case it's better to keep that logic decoupled from the view. I'm not sure how to put the window dimensions in your store with those hooks, but if you were just using React alone and not a global MobX store, it would probably work great.